# Firefox reinstalled, but not xul-ext-webaccounts

Tags: apt, software-installation, firefox

I wanted to reinstall Firefox, so what I did was:

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox
```

And this was the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  firefox* xul-ext-webaccounts*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 2 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 98.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 200410 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing xul-ext-webaccounts (0.5-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing firefox (37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for firefox (37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
```

Then I did:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

And this was the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  fonts-lyx
The following NEW packages will be installed
  firefox
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/40.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 98.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package firefox.
(Reading database ... 200295 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../firefox_37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox (37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Setting up firefox (37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
Please restart all running instances of firefox, or you will experience problems.
```

So what about the `xul-ext-webaccounts` that was removed when I purged Firefox, what is that, and should that not also get reinstalled? If it does need to get reinstalled, then how do I do this? Do I just run?:

```
sudo apt-get install xul-ext-webaccounts
```

Or do I do something else?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Package Information:**

```
firefox:
  Installed: 37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Candidate: 37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     37.0+build2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: For the record, the correct wat to reinstall packafes is: sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename

Also why do you exactly needed to reinstall?

Comment: @xangua: Yes, I knew it was something like that, but I just couldn't remember exactly at the time what the right reinstall command was. I needed to reinstall it because I forgot which browser I may or may not have slightly corrupted, I also forgot in which way I may or may not have corrupted it, so I thought, just to be on the safe side, that I should reinstall it.

Comment: @xangua: But anyway, that is not the point, the point is do I need this other package which was removed during the purging, but not reinstalled during to the installation? And if so, then what is the best way of reinstalling it? I would also like to know though what the other package is and its purpose in life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Ubuntu accounts like Launchpad or UbuntuOne then yes, you need this extension and need to:

```
sudo apt-get install xul-ext-webaccounts
```

to allow auto-log-on...  **;-)**